# Connection two raspberry PI via Wi-Fi direct

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, wpa-supplicant, iot

I wanted to play with the Wi-Fi direct protocol and really understand it as I want to pretend I have a sensor network that follows the pattern:

1. wake up
2. establish a network
3. trade data
4. disconnect
5. wait for next window
6. and repeat.

I have come close, but I can't quite figure out how to get the full protocol to work.

I started with two identical Raspberry PI 4's running Raspbian 10.
I have added the following packages:

```
openssl-server, bison, flex, build-essential, 
libglib2.0-dev, dbus-glib-1-dev, libssl-dev, libreadline-dev
```

I have downloaded and compiled the following:

```
desktop-file-utils, libnl, wpa_supplicant-2.9
```

The `wpa_suuplicant-2.9` was build and configured using http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/wpa_supplicant.html and the information from README-P2P

running `iw list` shows P2P-client, P2P-GO, P2P-device as being supported

I have modified `wpa_supplicant.conf` adding the following information:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
device_name=My P2P Device *<device number>*
device_type=1-0050F204-1
```

running `wpa_cli` then running `p2p_find` allows each device to find a printer that is nearby, but not each other

I have played with using `p2p_group_add` on one of the pis.  By using it, I can get the other pi to see the one which I did the `p2p_group_add` via `p2p_find`.  I haven't fully figured out this procedure yet; however, the problem with `p2p_group_add` is it skips GO negotiation.  This in my mind defeats the purpose of using Wi-Fi direct as I want each pi to take a turn as GO so I can distribute its workload across all devices.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Tim

Answer (score 0):

I needed to go get an external wifi adapter (I got one for each raspberry pi to keep them identical for my make belief scenario above)

Tested the steps above using an external wifi adapter that contained the rtl8192eu chipset.  Once the driver was compiled and added, it started working.